# trying to move value from edit text and spinner

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner

I want to get the value from a edit text and values from 3 spinners and calculate the value. Below is the code I have so far, remember that I am beyond new at this. I do not know how to get the value rollPrice to equal B3 in the formula as it gives me an error since rollPrice is put into a string.

**Clarification edit. The slength, swidth, and sthick are values selected from spinners. the rollPrice is an edit text the user puts the price into and then selects the values from the 3 spinners, and the formula will compute the MSF price.

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

            try{

                // Change the billBeforeTip to the new input

                rollCost = Double.parseDouble(arg0.toString());

            }

            catch(NumberFormatException e){

                rollCost = 0.0;

            }

    };

    private void calculate(){

         String B5 = swidth.getSelectedItem().toString();
         String B6 = slength.getSelectedItem().toString();
         String B4 = sthick.getSelectedItem().toString();

         MSF=1000/(Double.parseDouble(B5)/12*Double.parseDouble(B6))*Double.parseDouble(B‌​3);


    }
```

Comment: Not sure i understand your question or what you are doing converting to string and back to double and back to string again.. very confusing.  please post your code and your logcat

Answer (score 0):

Because you have mentioned that you are using EditTexts. I would suggest you to use 
(your question is unclear, I have assumed swidth,slength and sthick are edittexts)

```
         String B5 = swidth.getText().toString();
         String B6 = slength.getText().toString();
         String B4 = sthick.getText().toString();
```

instead of

```
         String B5 = swidth.getSelectedItem().toString();
         String B6 = slength.getSelectedItem().toString();
         String B4 = sthick.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: I made an edit for clarification. The 3 values of the swidth, slength, and sthick are selected from spinners. the rollprice is from an edit text the user puts a price into

Comment: what are the values of the spinner items ?